# How to implement digital filters in Core Audio?

Tags: ios, objective-c, filter, signal-processing, audiounit

I have a question about the implementation of digital filters in CoreAudio. I'm in big trouble because it is a few weeks I'm trying to understand how to implement them. The basic idea is this: while I talk to the iPhone's microphone, my voice is filtered by a low-pass filter or high-pass or bandpass.

I Studied the books "Learning Core Audio" for the implementation of the CoreAudio (Although I had to work it a few weeks and do research, but now work very well) and the book "Digital Signal Processing" (very famous because i saw him indicated always in discussions dedicated to the filters).

Book of DSP I understand this: I must Create a filter, a sort of kernel filter that is a kind of "mask" to be applied to the signal itself. In this state the filter is said "Impulse Response" or also is said IIR. Now I apply the mask to signal by a function convolution becoming a FIR filter. What I have written is this correct?

I tried to implement what is written, taking even the AudioGraph application example as with the Documentation, but nothing. Does not work.

I also found a document which explained in a simple way what to do (the name is "Creating FIR Filters in C ++") where the algorithms of the filters were mentioned, but even here, once Implemented have not worked.

For this is coming to me the doubt: maybe something else I have to do with the signal that I get? The only thing that I understand is I have to convert the signal in Sint16. I did, but then what? What should I do to implement a digital filter?

For this I ask for help. I have no one to confront and so now I'm going blind. I leave you with my current code of CoreAudio, I works perfectly, even on devices, but, perhaps, may be some wrong setting?

```
    AudioComponentDescription AudioCompDesc;
    AudioCompDesc.componentType = kAudioUnitType_Output;
    AudioCompDesc.componentSubType = kAudioUnitSubType_RemoteIO;
    AudioCompDesc.componentManufacturer = kAudioUnitManufacturer_Apple;
    AudioCompDesc.componentFlags = 0;
    AudioCompDesc.componentFlagsMask = 0;

    AudioComponent RIOComponente = AudioComponentFindNext(NULL, &AudioCompDesc);
    CheckError(AudioComponentInstanceNew(RIOComponente, &strutturaAscolto.RIO), "Impossibile ottenre un'istanza dell'unità RIO");



    UInt32 oneFlag = 1;
    AudioUnitElement bus0 = 0;
    CheckError(AudioUnitSetProperty (strutturaAscolto.RIO, kAudioOutputUnitProperty_EnableIO, kAudioUnitScope_Output,bus0, &oneFlag, sizeof(oneFlag)), "Impossibile abilitare l'uscita RIO");

    AudioUnitElement bus1 = 1;
    CheckError(AudioUnitSetProperty(strutturaAscolto.RIO, kAudioOutputUnitProperty_EnableIO, kAudioUnitScope_Input, bus1, &oneFlag, sizeof(oneFlag)),"Imposibile abilitare l'ingresso RIO");



    strutturaAscolto.AudioAscoltoASBD.mSampleRate = 44100;
    strutturaAscolto.AudioAscoltoASBD.mFormatID = kAudioFormatLinearPCM;
    strutturaAscolto.AudioAscoltoASBD.mFormatFlags = kAudioFormatFlagIsSignedInteger | kAudioFormatFlagsNativeEndian | kLinearPCMFormatFlagIsPacked;
    strutturaAscolto.AudioAscoltoASBD.mBytesPerPacket = 4;
    strutturaAscolto.AudioAscoltoASBD.mFramesPerPacket = 1;
    strutturaAscolto.AudioAscoltoASBD.mBytesPerFrame = 4;
    strutturaAscolto.AudioAscoltoASBD.mChannelsPerFrame = 2;
    strutturaAscolto.AudioAscoltoASBD.mBitsPerChannel = 16;


    CheckError(AudioUnitSetProperty (strutturaAscolto.RIO, kAudioUnitProperty_StreamFormat, kAudioUnitScope_Input, bus0, &strutturaAscolto.AudioAscoltoASBD, sizeof (strutturaAscolto.AudioAscoltoASBD)), "Impossibile impostare la descrizione audio (ASBD) per RIO sull'applicazione di ingresso 0");

    CheckError(AudioUnitSetProperty (strutturaAscolto.RIO, kAudioUnitProperty_StreamFormat, kAudioUnitScope_Output, bus1, &strutturaAscolto.AudioAscoltoASBD, sizeof (strutturaAscolto.AudioAscoltoASBD)), "Impossibile impostare la descrizione audio (ASBD) per RIO sull'applicazione di uscita 1");



    strutturaAscolto.SenoFrequenza = 30;
    strutturaAscolto.SenoFase = 0;

    AURenderCallbackStruct CallbackStruct;
    CallbackStruct.inputProc = ModulazioneAudio;
    CallbackStruct.inputProcRefCon = &strutturaAscolto;
    CheckError(AudioUnitSetProperty(strutturaAscolto.RIO, kAudioUnitProperty_SetRenderCallback, kAudioUnitScope_Global, bus0, &CallbackStruct, sizeof (CallbackStruct)), "Impossibile impostare il rendering di callback di RIO sul bus 0");

    CheckError(AudioUnitInitialize(strutturaAscolto.RIO), "Non è stato possibile inizializzare l'unità RIO");
    CheckError(AudioOutputUnitStart(strutturaAscolto.RIO), "Non è stato possibile avviare l'unità RIO");
```

While the function that should accommodate the filter is simply this.

```
static OSStatus ModulazioneAudio(void *inRefCon, AudioUnitRenderActionFlags *ioActionFlags, const AudioTimeStamp *inTimeStamp, UInt32 inBusNumber, UInt32 inNumberFrames,AudioBufferList *ioData) {

StrutturaAscolto *strutturaAscolto = (StrutturaAscolto*) inRefCon;


UInt32 bus1 = 1;
CheckError(AudioUnitRender(strutturaAscolto->RIO, ioActionFlags, inTimeStamp, bus1, inNumberFrames, ioData), "Non è stato possibile fare il render dell'unità RIO");

return noErr;
}
```

I leave with some filters, what I tested (not all).  Taking this algorithm for the high-pass filter of the document "Creating FIR Filters in C++":

```
int N = 1024;
float f_c = 5000/44100;
float ω_c = 2*M_PI*f_c;
int middle = N/2;
int i = -N/2;
float fltr[middle];

do {

    if (i == 0)  {
        fltr[middle] = 1 - 2*f_c;
    }
    else {
        fltr[i+middle] = -sin(ω_c*i)/(M_PI*i);
    }
    i++;
} while(i != N/2);
```

This i did by taking the book DPS (chapter 16) and is also referred to in the application AudioGraph.

```
void lowPassWindowedSincFilter( float *buf , float fc ) {

int i;
int m = 100;
float sum = 0;


for( i = 0; i < 101 ; i++ ) {
    if((i - m / 2) == 0 ) {
        buf[i] = 2 * M_PI * fc;
    }
    else {
        buf[i] = sin(2 * M_PI * fc * (i - m / 2)) / (i - m / 2);
    }
    buf[i] = buf[i] * (.54 - .46 * cos(2 * M_PI * i / m ));
}


for ( i = 0 ; i < 101 ; i++ ) {
    sum = sum + buf[i];
}

for ( i = 0 ; i < 101 ; i++ ) {
    buf[i] = buf[i] / sum;
}
}
```

As for the convolution function,  I used to Hamming, very simple that I found right here on StackOverflow.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1024; i++) {
    double multiplier = 0.5 * (1 - cos(2*M_PI*i/1023));
    dataOut[i] = multiplier * dataIn[i];
}
```

Thank you for your attention.

Comment: Never used it before, but I would look into [AudioKit](http://audiokit.io).

Comment: Hello, thank you for having responded me. I saw that recommend me to use a third-party kits. I saw the website you've linked, it looks interesting. But I would avoid it because it would mean throwing all the work just turned and then I would use mathematics to create the filters. But thank you anyway.

Comment: I'm having trouble trying to answer your question because you ask so many. It's unclear exactly what you're asking: How to build filters? How to add filtering to an audio stream? If your filter code is correct?

Could you simplify your questions down to 1 question, or summarize at the end a bullet point list of questions?

Comment: Hi, thank you for having responded to me. The real question is: How to implement digital filters in Core Audio? What I wrote was what I understood from the DSP book. I needed confirmation if what I had written was correct. In addition, reading other resources was written the relevant codes and what to do (I reported both source and code). I tried to put together the various arguments but unfortunately did not work. That is why I opened the question to ask if my reasoning based on what I read was wrong or just and how to move on.

Comment: @Fantastico did you able to find a solution using remote io and audio unit to implement low pass frequncy filter

Comment: Hi, from what I remember, it was not possible to implement filters effectively; or rather, the actual creation of a filter could not be implemented. So I decided to take advantage of what Apple made available to you. So I used AudioUnitSetParameter defining inside it the type of filter I wanted. (kLowPassParam_CutoffFrequency or kHipassParam_CutoffFrequency) plus the value that served as my cutoff frequency (managed by the user with a slider). This is a 6+ year old project in Objective-c. Today I wouldn't know how things have changed.